# Is it legal for a company to restrict people from re-selling (second hand) their products?

Tags: united-kingdom, sale-of-goods

"Hive Home" lock their hardware devices to specific accounts. If you move into a house with Hive products already connected to a previous user:

> you’ll need to **buy** a new Hive Hub. [source](https://community.hivehome.com/s/article/I-ve-moved-into-a-house-that-has-Hive-products-installed-what-should-I-do)

And what they don't say is: you have to **throw away the old one**. The old one is completely useless, and tied to previous person's account. It's like Apple saying once you tie a MacBook to an Apple ID, you can't disconnect it and cannot sell it to anyone.

**Is it legal** for a company to restrict people from re-selling (second hand) items - they call this "transferring ownership"? Both their app, and their human customer service representatives have told me I cannot transfer ownership or rename the account - as this is the same as transferring ownership.

Answer (score 7):

This is **not** prohibiting the resale. You can resell your old box, but you can not transfer your account, and since the box can't take a new account, it is not a useful item to anyone but the original account holder.

It is not illegal to make a resale *effectively impossible*, but you can not ban it under the [First Sale Doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-sale_doctrine) and [[Patent] Exhaustion Doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_doctrine_under_U.S._law).

Accounts are in this case not *sold items* but subscriptions and don't fall under First Sale but instead are running contracts - and can be regulated as the contracting parties put into the contract. This contract can ban the transfer (for money or free) of the contract.

Comment: The first sale doctrine in the US is essentially a copyright right. For a physical item the relevant IP framework would be patent  exhaustion. And the simple right of alienation in property rights.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Patent Exhaustion and First Sale seem to at times blend into one another at times, but good catch!

Comment: @GeorgeWhite The FirstSale doctine in ther US goes beyone copyright issues. For example it bans things like teh old UK "net conditions of sale" in which the publisher forbade resale in an altered cover. It bans an attempt to prohibit resale at an altered price, or in general to control the conditions of or prevent a resale.

Comment: @DavidSiegel yes, but in this case the resale isn't forbidden. it's just made valueless for such but as a spare part source.

Comment: @Trish I understand that, and i agree with the answer that the seller may decline to alter the account associated with the hardware in such a case. I was responding only to George White's comment that first sale "is essentially a copyright right."

Comment: @DavidSiegel - under what legal theory could a bookseller try to constrain resale? Did sellers of non-written items attempt this also? I think copyright *is* at the heart of the strings publishers used to try  to constrain resale.

Comment: @George White. Many books sold in the UK or the cmmonwealth used to carry a notice "This book is sold subject to the condition that it shall not be resold, lent or hired out in any form of cover or binding other than the one it is first sold in."  Sometimes "except in the US" was added.  I gather that this was enforceable in he UK, but not in the US due to the first sale doctrine. I don't know what the legal theory was, but it doesn't seem to have been a matter of copyright. [...]

Comment: That seems to be more a Trademark notice, where re-binding in a different backing could imply a different producer.

Comment: @George White. [...] In other cases there was a notice that "under the net conditions of sale this book is not to be solf at retail at a price less than the price shown on the back cover" and a list of prices for various commonwealth countries: Can, Aus, NZ, UK, etc. I gather this was to stop discount stores from undercutting regular booksellers. Again, I am not sure of the legal theory, but I don't see how copyright would have applied, and again i think that First Sale made this not enforceable in the US. I mostly saw this on PB books published in the 1960s and 70s, and some earlier.

Comment: @Trish I gather it was particularly aimed at subscription libraries that lent books for a fee, somewhat similar to the video rental stores so common in the 1990s.

Comment: There may be a non-copyright legal theory involved but I do not see any examples of product other than copyrightable items. No toys, hammers, cameras, dresses or bicycles.